# Numerical evaluation of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical, polynomial-math, polynomials

I've written some Matlab procedures that evaluate orthogonal polynomials, and as a sanity check I was trying to ensure that their dot product would be zero.

But, while I'm fairly sure there's not much that can go wrong, I'm finding myself with a slightly curious behaviour. My test is quite simple:

```
x = -1:.01:1;
for i0=0:9
  v1 = poly(x, i0);
  for i1=0:i0
    v2 = poly(x,i1);
    fprintf('%d, %d: %g\n', i0, i1, v1*v2');
  end
end
```

(Note the dot product `v1*v2'` needs to be this way round because `x` is a horizontal vector.)

Now, to cut to the end of the story, I end up with values close to 0 (order of magnitude about 1e-15) for pairs of degrees that add up to an odd number (i.e., `i0+i1=2k+1`). When `i0==i1` I expect the dot product not to be 0, but this also happens when `i0+i1=2k`, which I didn't expect.

To give you some more details, I initially did this test with Chebyshev polynomials of first kind. Now, they are orthogonal with respect to the weight

```
1 ./ sqrt(1-x.^2)
```

which goes to infinity when `x` goes to 1. So I thought that leaving this term out could be the cause of non-zero dot products.

But then, I did the same test with Legendre polynomials, and I get exactly the same result: when the sum of the degrees is even, the dot product is definitely far from 0 (order of magnitude 1e2).

One last detail, I used the trigonometric formula `cos(n*acos(x))` to evaluate the Chebyshev polynomials, and I tried the recursive formula as well as one of the formulas involving the binomial coefficient to evaluate the Legendre polynomials.

Can anyone explain this odd (pun intended) behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being misled by symmetry. Both [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind) and [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) polynomials are eigenfunctions of the parity operator, which means that they can all be classified as *either* odd or even functions. I guess the same goes for your custom orthogonal polynomials.

Due to this symmetry, if you multiply a polynomial `P_n(x)` by `P_m(x)`, then the result will be an odd function if `n+m` is odd, and it will be even otherwise. You're computing `sum_k P_n(x_k)*P_m(x_k)` for a symmetric set of `x_k` values around the origin. This implies that for odd `n+m` you will *always* get zero. Try computing `sum_k P_n(x_k)*Q_m(x_k)` with `P` a Legendre, and `Q` a Chebyshev polynomial. My point is that for `n+m=odd`, the result doesn't tell you anything about orthogonality or the accuracy of your integration.

The problem is that probably you're not integrating accurately enough. These orthogonal polynomials defined on `[-1,1]` vary quite rapidly on their domain, especially close to the boundaries (`x==+-1`). Try increasing the points of your integration, using a non-equidistant mesh, or a proper integration using `integral`.

Final note: I'd advise you against calling your functions `poly`, since [that's a MATLAB built-in](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/poly.html). (And so is [`legendre`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legendre.html).)

Comment: Right. Ok, so I tried out `integral` but I'm still getting non-zero results, albeit smaller than before (order 1e-1, 1e-2). Very good point about symmetry though, it makes perfect sense. (I didn't actually call any function `poly` or `legendre`, it was just to simplify the code for the post. Thanks for the reminder though!)

Comment: @Roberto do you also get this large scalar products for Chebyshev and Legendre polynomials?

Comment: No, actually if I use <code>integral</code> on the product between a Chebyshev and a Legendre polynomial I get very small values (around 1e-15). Curious...

Comment: @Roberto there's your answer:) This means that now your integration is accurate, so something's off with your custom polynomials. Either they vary *very* rapidly (I don't think so, but you should plot them anyway), or they're not orthogonalized properly. You should use `integral` in the orthogonalization process as well, or else the result will also be inaccurate.

Comment: Ok, here we go. So, using `integral` everything works as it should after all. The results with Legendre polynomials is close enough to 0, and the problem I just had was with the Chebyshev polynomials. But I forgot that you need to divide their product by `sqrt(1-x.^2)`, once I included that factor then `integral` started giving me the correct results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Roberto No problem, I'm glad I could help:)